# Force Take the Mouse and KeyBoard Control away from VM Workstation

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

Sometimes the image OS inside a VM Workstation can hang (or the VMWorkstation itself can hang), and when that happens my mouse and keyboard control were trapped by the image OS.

Is there anyway to force take the mouse and the keyboard controll back to the host OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't **Ctrl + Alt** (**Cmd + Opt** in Mac OS) take the control back to the Host OS? That's the standard way of doing it. Unfortunately, if that doesn't work, the host OS is hanged as well. The only way would be to press **Ctrl + Alt + Delete** (or **Ctrl + Shift + Esc**) to bring up the Task Manager.

Comment: I tried Ctrl + Alt + Delete, but it didn't work. Maybe at that time the host OS also hanged.

Comment: They are both hanged, unfortunately. The same thing happens for me in Mac OS; running an OS in a VM is very resource intensive. **Ctrl + Shift + Esc** doesn't work either? It would normally invoke Task Manager directly, if possible.